# Leiningen: how to exclude dependencies when uberjaring?

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen

When using leiningen to build Clojure applications, how can certain dependencies be excluded from being included in the JAR file when using `lein uberjar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `provided` entry for the leiningen profile.

```
 :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"]
                                 [prismatic/dommy "0.1.3"]
                                 [org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on "1.50"]]}
            :provided {:dependencies [[org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on "1.50"]]}}
```

One common use case is `bouncycastle` that needs to be excluded from the signed JAR and provided externally using its own jar file in runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to what Guillermo suggested modify your project's :profiles to include something along the lines of:

```
:provided {:dependencies [[org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on "1.50"]
                          [org.bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk15on "1.50"]]}
```

(The specific versions may vary.)

Trouble is that if you use a Clojure wrapper library (such as `clj-pgp` or `thi.ng/crypto`), it forces inclusion of the jar in the uberjar, breaking the process.

My solution was to fork the library and push it to clojars after modifying its `project.clj` to uses provided dependencies.

More details here: http://side-effects-bang.blogspot.com/2015/02/deploying-uberjars-that-use-bouncy.html

Answer (score 0):

In the `project.clj` under `:dependencies` you can add exclusions for specific jars like this:

`[test/test-jar "1.0" :exclusions [sample-exclusion/test-exclusions]]`