# Leiningen wont exclude namespaces from uberjar

Tags: clojure, compilation, jvm, leiningen

I have a project where I want certain parts of the code to be able to run on a local environment, and other parts which depend on libraries that only run on a remote environment. E.g.

```
src/app/core.clj <- can run anywhere
src/app/sandbox/remote_only.clj <- depnds on libs that only function in remote environ
```

where `src/app/core.clj` is

```clj
(ns app.core
  (:gen-class))
(defn -main [] (println "Hello, World!"))
```

and `src/app/sandbox/remote_only.clj` is

```clj
(ns app.sandbox.remote-only
  (:require
    [uncomplicate.commons.core :refer [with-release]]
    [uncomplicate.neanderthal
     [native :refer [dv dge]]
     [core :refer [mv mv!]]]))
```

I want to be able to `uberjar` and run the code located in `core.clj` on my local machine without pulling in `remote_only.clj` which will cause the program to fail locally. According to the docs, Leiningen should be able to accomplish this using profiles and uberjar exclusions e.g.:

```clj
(defproject app "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]]
  :profiles {:uberjar {:main app.core
                       :init-ns app.core
                       :aot :all}
             :remote {:init-ns app.sandbox.remote_only
                      :dependencies [[uncomplicate/neanderthal "0.43.1"]]}} ; these deps will fail locally
  :uberjar-exclusions [#".*sandbox.*"]
  :repl-options {:init-ns app.core})
```

compiling the uberjar here will result in:

```
❯ lein uberjar
Compiling app.core
Compiling app.sandbox.remote-only
Syntax error macroexpanding at (remote_only.clj:1:1).
Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at app.sandbox.remote-only/loading (remote_only.clj:1).
Could not locate uncomplicate/commons/core__init.class, uncomplicate/commons/core.clj or uncomplicate/commons/core.cljc on classpath.
```

So, explicitly its trying to compile the class that was specifically excluded.

I thought that this kind of problem could be avoided by removing the `:all` tag from `:aot` compilation. E.g.:

```clj
(defproject app "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]]
  :profiles {:uberjar {:main app.core
                       :init-ns app.core
                       :aot [app.core]}
             :remote {:init-ns app.sandbox.remote_only
                      :dependencies [[uncomplicate/neanderthal "0.43.1"]]}} ; these deps will fail locally
  :uberjar-exclusions [#".*sandbox.*"]
  :repl-options {:init-ns app.core})
```

which causes other problems:

```
❯ lein uberjar
Compiling app.core
Created /Users/warrenronsiek/Projects/app/target/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /Users/warrenronsiek/Projects/app/target/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
~/Projects/app                                                                                                                                                                                              5s 15:47:37
❯ java -jar ./target/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/Var
```

I've tried playing around with all kinds of `:exclusions`, `:jar-exclusions` and regexes. Variations of this question have been asked multiple times ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246740/exclude-certain-clj-namespaces-from-compilation-in-leiningen),  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228543/leiningen-how-to-exclude-dependencies-when-uberjaring)) Nothing works.

How do I get Leiningen to compile uberjars and ignore the specified file(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with changing `:aot :all` to `:aot [app.core]` but when you tried to run the JAR, you are running the *library* version instead of the whole application version:

```
java -jar ./target/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

That doesn't include Clojure or any dependencies. You want:

```
java -jar ./target/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this particular setup with the "exclusions" features.

One workaround would be to create sub-projects for the "local" & "remote" parts of your app, which could then be used by a higher-level "total" project.

```
app
  app-local
  app-remote
```

where each of the 3 is a separate Lein project.  `app-local` and `app-remote` could be developed in isolation.  The top-level `app` project then uses has the 2 sub-projects as dependencies (and therefore only works in the remote/full environment).

The Lein feature [checkouts](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies) allows you to develop in all 3 repos simultaneously, which is a huge help.  It is much faster than the alternative of using `lein install`, which is slow, manual, repetitive, and error-prone.

---

P.S.  Did you experiment with using `lein jar` instead of `lein uberjar`?